# Can't save array in sessionStorage on component init in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am fetching data in component and want to save in `sessionStorage` through service `EquipmentStoreService`, but it doesn't save in sessionStorage. How can I handle this issue?

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  equipments: Equipment[];

  constructor(private equipmentService: EquipmentService,
              private equipmentStore: EquipmentStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.equipmentService.getItems()
      .subscribe( data => {
          this.equipmentStore.updateThisStore(data);
          this.equipments = this.equipmentStore.all();
      });
  }
}
```

This is my store service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EquipmentStoreService {
  private static STORAGE_KEY = 'current-equipments';
  equipments: Array<Equipment>;

  constructor () {
    this.equipments = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(EquipmentStoreService.STORAGE_KEY) || '[]');
  }

  updateStore() {
    localStorage.setItem(EquipmentStoreService.STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(this.equipments));
  }

  updateThisStore(equipments: Equipment[]) {
    this.equipments = equipments;
    this.updateStore();
  }

  all() {
    return this.equipments;
  }
}
```

Comment: i do not see anyway you are calling updateStore

Comment: @Sajeetharan updateThisStore calls updateStore

Comment: I think you are setting the data in localStorage and getting it in the sessionStorage may be it is producing issue.

Comment: @fizakhan you are right, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting the data in localStorage and getting it in the sessionStorage.

Update your store service like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EquipmentStoreService {
  private static STORAGE_KEY = 'current-equipments';
  equipments: Array<Equipment>;

  constructor () {
    this.equipments = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(EquipmentStoreService.STORAGE_KEY) || '[]');
  }

 updateStore() {
   sessionStorage.setItem(EquipmentStoreService.STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(this.equipments));
 }

 updateThisStore(equipments: Equipment[]) {
   this.equipments = equipments;
   this.updateStore();
 }

 all() {
  return this.equipments;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In the updateStore function, you are saving array in `localStorage` not `sessionStorage`. Use `sessionStorage.setItem` function to save item in session storage.